# Gatekeeper notification doesn't show location of application

Tags: macos, high-sierra, homebrew, spotlight, gatekeeper

I just received a system notification that an application I downloaded with Homebrew was not allowed to launch. This is fine, but the notification gives me no information about where this app resides. I downloaded many applications with Homebrew and this is most likely inside a package. Using Console or some other method, how can I find out where this app is on my file system? I am wishing the system notification window showed the path to the file in question so it can be removed or allowed.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: well my first question is, do you trust that file, if so you can install it by changing your security preference ! if you do not trust, the file will not exist as Launcher.app

Comment: I had no option to "trust" the app since it was a triggered launch. I assume it was part of a package that was installed when I downloaded an app via Homebrew Cask – which puts files in the Applications folder. It was most likely an app to finish installation or setup and now that it hasn't been allowed to run that setup most likely didn't occur.My security is set to "Known Developers" and "App Store" – I don't want to turn off Gatekeeper.

Comment: My response helped me figure out where the app is. If was triggered upon restart it had to be in "Login Items" and sure enough it's there. Like I mentioned it is part of a package – in it's resources folder. mdfind did not locate it.

Answer (score 1):

Spotlight might be the easiest

```
mdfind Launcher.app
```

If you get too many results, `mdfind -name Launcher` or `mdfind -name Launcher.app` might narrow the scope. I'm able to locate all the things I have installed via homebrew so you can check that for another install by trying the results of `brew list` and feeding one other package to check spotlight.

Comment: Thank you. I had high hopes, but no dice. Does Gatekeeper move the file somewhere else if it's been blocked?

Comment: No @John - it just pauses the launching. If it's damaged, you get a different message about it going to trash. I can't believe you have no hits for Launcher.app but what about just Launcher without .app - I'll add a second mdfind for just the name, not the contents in case you get lots of hits for the overall `mdfind`